# How to handle Null or Blank in a filter activity logic expressions

Tags: azure-synapse

I am trying to filter out the null record from previous lookup activity in azure synapse workspace. To do this, I have used the below mentioned expressions in filter activity. But I am not able to get rid of the null records in the filter activity output. I have used the coalesce() function also to do that.

FYI, I know there is **IsNull** expression in data flow activity, but I don't want to use Data flow in pipeline as the pipeline is small and dataflow execution is extra cost.

PFB, details and attached screenshot. [image]
[image]

Approach used : Filter activity to filter null records using coalesce() function and without coalesce().
Expression:

1. @if(equals(coalesce(activity('LookupID').output.value[0].ID,''),''), true,false)
2. @if(equals(activity('LookupID').output.value[0].ID, null), false,true)
3. @if(equals(activity('LookupID').output.value[0].ID, ''),''), false,true)

With any of the above expressions, the filter output has all the records including null value records.
Please share your suggestion if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the filter condition. You can use the following condition instead to filter out null records returned from look up activity.

- I have a look up activity called `Lookup id` which returns `id and gname` where 1 id record is null and 2 are not null.

[image]

- Now I have used the following dynamic content as the `items` and `condtion` for filter activity:

```
items: @activity('Lookup id').output.value

conditions: @if(equals(item().id, null), false,true)
```

[image]

- The filter would work as expected and the output would be as shown below (only two records returned):

[image]